# Powershell Find .Docx if they contain string like "test" and exort file name to csv

Tags: powershell

docx file via powershell if they contain a specific sting within them and export the fullname (full name) to a csv i almost have but how do i export to a csv

```
#Instance of word
$Word=NEW-Object –comobject Word.Application
$Word.visible = $False

#take list of .docx
Get-ChildItem "C:\test\test1\Desktop\Pictures" -Recurse -file -Filter "*.docx" | %{

$Filename=$_.FullName

#open file and take content of word file
$Document=$Word.documents.open($Filename, $false, $true)
$range = $document.content
-***---THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE TO EXPORT TOO I THINK*** 
#if content have your word, print path of word file
If($range.Text -like "*test*"){
    $Filename
}

$word.Documents.Close($false)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is all you output, simply assign the whole pipeline to a variable:

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem ... |% {
  # ...
}
```

Now you just need to construct some objects that can meaningfully be exported to CSV, then pipe to `Export-CSV`:

```
$FileNames |Select @{Name='Path';Expression={$_}} |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv
```